# Difference between two Bloomberg codes SIX Market

Tags: finance, bloomberg

23

Bloomberg always have two codes for the same instruments. For example, for CIE CIE FINANCIERE
RICHEMO, Bloomberg has CFR SE and CFR SW.

I am wondering what is the difference between these two codes?

Comment: Hi and welcome to the forum. Perhaps this question is better asked to Bloomberg's help desk?

Answer (score 1):

SE is the SIX exchange, SW is the composite for Switzerland (which I think in this case is the same thing because Richemont is only listed on SIX in Switerland).
A more self-explanatory example is GY (Xetra) vs GR (German composite). If you type `SAP GR Equity VWAP <Go>` and click on "12) By Exchange", you will see what exchanges are included in the composite (there is GY, the main exchange, plus a few others).
Then you can also try SAP EU Equity which is the European composite - it includes all the GR exchanges plus a number of non German exchanges where SAP is trading.